# The Linux command line for beginner | Creating folders and files

Tags: command-line, files, directory

I'm trying to go through the tutorial for creating folders and files, however when I followed the instructions I'm getting a different result. When I type `ls` it shows a bunch of stuff instead of dir 1 dir 2 dir 3.

Comment: Please update your question with whar commnds you are using, what results you get, and how that differs from the expectd result.

Answer (score 2):

`ls` shows a list of *all* the files and directories (folders) in a directory.

You can use `ls -d */` to only list the directories.

To create a new directory, `mkdir new-folder` (replace new-folder with the name you want to).

To create a new (empty file), `touch filename`.

Afterwards, you can edit the contents of the file, with `nano filename` (You can directly create a new file with nano as well).

To exit nano, press  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>x</kbd> , followed by  <kbd>y</kbd> (to confirm saving) and  <kbd>Enter</kbd> .

Answer (score 1):

I could think of a possibility that you created the directories in a different place than the tutorial, perhaps.

The default command prompt of ubuntu would look like

```
norio@payapaya:~$
```

where `norio` is my user name, and `payapaya` is the name of the computer, and `~` means that I am in the home directory.

If I do

```
norio@payapaya:~$ ls
```

I get a lot of directories and files including `Desktop`, `Documents`, `Downloads`, etc. which exists by default in ubuntu.

Your tutorial might have first created a dedicated directory (`tutoriaaaal` in the following example.) and created `dir1`, `dir2`, etc. inside it, like this:

```
norio@payapaya:~$ mkdir tutoriaaaal
norio@payapaya:~$ cd tutoriaaaal/
norio@payapaya:~/tutoriaaaal$ mkdir dir1
norio@payapaya:~/tutoriaaaal$ mkdir dir2
norio@payapaya:~/tutoriaaaal$ mkdir dir3
norio@payapaya:~/tutoriaaaal$ ls 
dir1  dir2  dir3
norio@payapaya:~/tutoriaaaal$
```

The command `cd` on the second line means 'change directory', and it is used to change the working directory to the specified one.